# Create file, move 1MB with lseek() and then write one byte into file

Tags: c, shell, unix

I try to create file using open(), then move 1MB with lseek() and finally need to write 1 byte into that file.

There is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int f_open(const char *name);

int f_open(const char *name){
   int dskr;
   dskr = open( name, O_CREAT );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
      perror( name );
      exit(1);
   }
   printf( "dskr = %d\n", dskr );
   return dskr;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
   int d;
   int f;
   char buf[20];

   if( argc != 2 ){
      printf( "Naudojimas:\n %s failas_ar_katalogas\n", argv[0] );
      exit( 255 );
   }
   d = f_open( argv[1] );

   lseek( d, 1, SEEK_SET );

   f = write( d, buf, 1);

   return 0;
}
```

File created correctly, but I am not sure if move 1MB works good and also write not working. I am not sure because program runs correctly but the size of it is 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I am not sure if move 1MB works good` You're moving to byte `1`. Thats not one mega byte, thats a single byte.

Comment: So, then I should change that to 1048576? Because it's 1MB, or there any other way?

Comment: Yes, that would work. (Or maybe `lseek` to one less, which together with the written byte will then make exactly 1MB. Note that `buf` is not initialised, so that you write a garbage value.)

Comment: Ok, and what about write 1 byte into that file also?

Comment: ***Why*** are you not sure? What happens when you run your program? What is the size of the file? What's happening and what did you expect to happen? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The program doesn't check the value returned by lseek or write, so even if one of those fails your program will `return 0` and appear to succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few bugs:

```
   dskr = open( name, O_CREAT );
```

The flags to `open()` must include one of `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`.  So you probably want `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT`.

```
   lseek( d, 1, SEEK_SET );
```

The offset to `lseek` is in bytes.  If you want to seek 1 megabyte, you have to convert that into bytes.  A convenient and readable way is to write `1024*1024`.

Also, you ought to check the return value of `lseek` and report any errors appropriately.

```
   f = write( d, buf, 1);
```

You never initialized `buf[0]`, so you are writing one byte of garbage.  (Anyway, there is no point in having `buf` be 20 bytes if you are never going to use the other 19.)

Also, you ought to check the return value of `write` and handle errors or short writes appropriately.

Comment: So, I it might be better to change `buf` from 20 to 1?

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas: Yes.  Or just declare `char c;`, store something there (`c = 'x';`), and do `write(d, &c, 1)`.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's great idea. I have one more question. When I move 1MB and write 1 byte, then my file size should be 1048577?

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas: Correct.  Note that, if the file did not previously exist or was smaller than 1 MB, then the rest of the file will be filled with zero bytes, and on many systems it will be a sparse file (look it up).

Comment: I wanna Thank you very much for helping me!!